# Wordpress pagination not working in search result page

Tags: php, pagination, search

I have a problem with pagination on search results page. The page links appear, but when i click onto page 2, it gives me a 404 error.

Page 1 : http://templategraphy.com/wp-demo/businessguru/?s=Blog+Image (page 1)

Page 2 : http://templategraphy.com/wp-demo/businessguru/page/2/?s=Blog+Image (Page not found)

search.php

```
<?php 

            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                    $args = array( 'paged' => $paged );
                    $the_query= new WP_Query($args);

                ?>
        <div>

         <?php  if (have_posts()) : ?>

        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('item'); ?>>

        <?php

       $featuredImage = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );


       if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {


        echo '<a class="single-image link-icon" href="'.get_the_permalink().'">';

       echo '<img src="'.$featuredImage.'" style="width:213px; height:110px;" />';

        echo '</a>';

       }

       ?>


      </div>


    <?php  endwhile; ?>


    <?php
      next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages );
      previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );
    ?>

   <?php 
    // clean up after our query
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
    ?>
    </div>

    <?php  else : ?>

   <h1 class="title">Not Found</h1>

   <p>Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>

   <?php  endif; ?>

  </div>
```

Please suggest some solutions.

Comment: Thanks @PieterGoosen for your suggestion but my problem is not solved i tried your code but its not working and please see my edited code and tell me where i am wrong..

Comment: Suggest some solutions searching and pagination both are not working at the same time please see my code and suggest me what i am doing wrong in my code

Answer (score 1):

okay sorry for mentioning only link as an answer.. if first pagination link shows 404 error that should be a permalink issue. but to u its second page so definitely it because of some code mistake. please check this code.

```
/*Loop Pagination - A WordPress script for creating paginated links on archive-type pages.*/

function loop_pagination( $args = array() ) {
global $wp_rewrite, $wp_query;

/* If there's not more than one page, return nothing. */
if ( 1 >= $wp_query->max_num_pages )
    return;

/* Get the current page. */
$current = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1 );

/* Get the max number of pages. */
$max_num_pages = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

/* Get the pagination base. */
$pagination_base = $wp_rewrite->pagination_base;

/* Set up some default arguments for the paginate_links() function. */
$defaults = array(
    'base'         => add_query_arg( 'paged', '%#%' ),
    'format'       => '',
    'total'        => $max_num_pages,
    'current'      => $current,
    'prev_next'    => true,
    //'prev_text'  => __( '&laquo; Previous' ), // This is the WordPress default.
    //'next_text'  => __( 'Next &raquo;' ), // This is the WordPress default.
    'show_all'     => false,
    'end_size'     => 1,
    'mid_size'     => 1,
    'add_fragment' => '',
    'type'         => 'plain',

    // Begin loop_pagination() arguments.
    'before'       => '<nav class="pagination loop-pagination">',
    'after'        => '</nav>',
    'echo'         => true,
);

/* Add the $base argument to the array if the user is using permalinks. */
if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() && !is_search() )
    $defaults['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( get_pagenum_link() ) . "{$pagination_base}/%#%" );

/* Allow developers to overwrite the arguments with a filter. */
$args = apply_filters( 'loop_pagination_args', $args );

/* Merge the arguments input with the defaults. */
$args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

/* Don't allow the user to set this to an array. */
if ( 'array' == $args['type'] )
    $args['type'] = 'plain';

/* Get the paginated links. */
$page_links = paginate_links( $args );

/* Remove 'page/1' from the entire output since it's not needed. */
$page_links = preg_replace( 
    array( 
        "#(href=['\"].*?){$pagination_base}/1(['\"])#",  // 'page/1'
        "#(href=['\"].*?){$pagination_base}/1/(['\"])#", // 'page/1/'
        "#(href=['\"].*?)\?paged=1(['\"])#",             // '?paged=1'
        "#(href=['\"].*?)&\#038;paged=1(['\"])#"         // '&#038;paged=1'
    ), 
    '$1$2', 
    $page_links 
);

/* Wrap the paginated links with the $before and $after elements. */
$page_links = $args['before'] . $page_links . $args['after'];

/* Allow devs to completely overwrite the output. */
$page_links = apply_filters( 'loop_pagination', $page_links );

/* Return the paginated links for use in themes. */
if ( $args['echo'] )
    echo $page_links;
else
    return $page_links;
 }
```

Comment: @payal : please mark it as the answer so that it will help others too